# jQuery click function more variables

Tags: jquery, click

Hello I would like to ask if its possible to add there more variables with a logical sum. Here is my code and I would like to use more variables, something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[]" value="1">Apple
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[]" value="2">Blackberry
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[]" value="3">Blueberry
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[]" value="4">Orange
<br>
<input type="text" name="fruit">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="odeslat" value="submit"> Submit </button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
$(function () {
    $('input[value="1"]' || 'input[value="2"]').click(function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('input[name="fruit"]').on('keyup', function () {
                if($(this).val() != '') {
                    $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        }
    });
});
```

This code doesnt work `$('input[value="1"]' || 'input[value="2"]')` and I dont know how to fix it.

online version http://jsfiddle.net/krizvite/hk05wps6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hk05wps6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `OR` condition in selectors.

The selector will throw Syntax Error.

```
$('input[value="1"]' || 'input[value="2"]')
```

You can use following selector to get the first matched element.

```
$('input[value="1"], input[value="2"]').first()
```

The selector `$('input[value="1"], input[value="2"]')` selects the `input` elements having value `1` and/or `2`. If both the elements are present both will be selected. To get the first selected element, use `first()` on the selector.

Comment: Welcome @VítězslavKříž. Glad that helped.

Comment: can you please help me with a second issue I have with jquery? Solving here: This would be really really helpful for me! THX again so much!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473403/how-to-ensure-a-different-option-with-different-checkbox/34473913#34473913